# Flask crashes blender when ran in command line

Tags: python, command-line

I'm trying to get a flask server to run in blender with `blender -P app.py template.blend`, however whenever I do that, it opens up two black windows and the crashes shortly after. I'm getting the error

```
Error: Cannot read file '/PROJECT_DIR/blender': No such file or directory

Blender quit
```

Full log can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/sZBVPBpC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off debug mode solves the issue